# Getting a 'data.slice is not a function' Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, mat-table

I'm getting the issue *data.slice is not a function* in Angular. Before searching the help here, I've looked through similar issues, but the problem is still not been solved.

So, I have a component.ts class:

```
export class SportsmenListComponent implements OnInit {
  userDetails: any;
  spd: any;
  users: User[]= [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Id', 'Name', 'Surname', 'BirthDate', 'Email', 'Username', 'UserType'];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true })
  paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true })
  sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(public service: UserService, private toastr: ToastrService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
    this.userDetailsList();

  }

  public userDetailsList() {
    this.service.getUserProfile().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.userDetails = res
        this.service.getUsersUsers(this.userDetails.belongSection.id, 'Sportsman').subscribe(
          (result) => {
            this.dataSource.data = (result as User[])
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        )
      },
      err =>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

The datasource realization is in the method userDetailsList(). I'm trying to assign the data to the table using the http. The requests work fine, so it's the issue from the client-side.

My component.html code is:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z1">
   <!-- {{userDetails.belongSection.name}} -->
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.id }} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Surname">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Surname </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.surname}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="BirthDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> BirthDate </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.birthDate | date: 'longDate'}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Email </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.email}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Username">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Username </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.userName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="UserType">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> User Type </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="left-text"> {{element.userType}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5]"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
```

So, I'm getting this error:
[image]

**Important note**, I was trying to use instead of `this.dataSource.data = (result as User[])`, other variant like:  `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result as User[])` and with that the issue is gone, but the data isn't showing in the table.

That's how the data is shown in the console:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a single user and not an array of users. (so it won't have array methods like `slice`.)

Comment: I second this opinion. It seems that you don't get an array of objects but only one single object.

Comment: yes, thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems that you only get a single object but not a list of objects try to add the result to an array and set this array as dataSource.

```
this.dataSource.data = [(result as User[])];
```

It's supposed to show one entry in the table at least. Just to make sure that the rest of the code works as expected.

Comment: yes, you're right, I've fixed the back-end part with that, everything works now, thanks!